Flyout menu using react context re-opens when closing it with its button
I am coding a FlyoutManager from which I can toggle every flyout menus in react app. I am trying to set the property to close when clicking outside. I found on another stackoverflow question that my clicking-outside function is triggered when I click the button to close it so it re-opens the flyout menu because it toggles the menu state twice.
Have you got some ideas to fix my problem ?
Here is the Header code simplified to my problem :
export const Header = () => {
    const {toggleFlyout} = useFlyout();
    return (
        <header>
            <div>
                /*
                    ...
                    Other components
                */
                <nav>
                    /*
                        ...
                        Other buttons
                    */
                    <button id="UserFlyout" onClick={() => toggleFlyout("UserFlyout")}>
                        User-logo
                    </button>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};

Here is the FlyoutContext Folder which contains the toggle function :
export const FlyoutContext = createContext();

export const FlyoutProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [flyout, setFlyout] = useState(null);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    const toggleFlyout = name => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        if (!isOpen) {
            setFlyout(name);
        } else {
            setFlyout(null);
        }
    }

    return (
        <FlyoutContext.Provider value={{flyout, toggleFlyout}}>
            {children}
        </FlyoutContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useFlyout = () => useContext(FlyoutContext);

Here is the FlyoutManager Folder
const FlyoutList = {
    UserFlyout: UserFlyout
};

export const FlyoutManager = () => {
    const {flyout, toggleFlyout} = useFlyout();
    
    const flyoutRef = useRef(null);

    const Flyout = FlyoutList[flyout];

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = event => {
            if (flyoutRef.current !== null && !flyoutRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
                toggleFlyout(flyout);
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handler);
        };
    }, [flyoutRef, flyout, toggleFlyout]);  

    if (!flyout) return null;

    return (
        <Flyout flyoutRef={flyoutRef}>
            <div ref={flyoutRef}>
                user flyout
            </div>
        </Flyout>
    );
};

Thanks a lot for your help
Some ideas might be to check if the mousedown event target is not the button. But because I use a context I can't access the id button in the FlyoutContext.

New answer
You were rigth, splitting into two idempotent functions - openFlyout and closeFlyout - was not a complete answer.
Instead, I've added a ref for the button to the context and checked if it's the button that has been clicked. Here's what the useEffect looks like now:
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      const isOutsideFlyout = !flyoutRef.current?.contains(event.target);
      const isOutsideButton = !flyoutButonRef.current?.contains(event.target);
      if (isOutsideFlyout && isOutsideButton) {
        closeFlyout();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    };
  }, [flyoutRef, flyout, closeFlyout]);

(the ? in flyoutRef.current?.contains is an Optional chaining operator, makes the condition shorter)
And here's the button:
import { useFlyout } from "./FlyoutContext";

export default function FlyoutButton() {
  const { toggleFlyout, flyoutButonRef } = useFlyout();

  return (
    <button ref={flyoutButonRef} onClick={() => toggleFlyout("UserFlyout")}>
      UserFlyout
    </button>
  );
}

Your sandbox for some reason didn't work for me, so I created a new one from the scratch and copied the code, but anyway here's working sandbox example
Former answer
You've got two options, one is quite diffucult while the other is really simple:

either you somehow put the mousedown handler on something that covers the entire thing, including the button,
or you can just split the toggleFlyout into two idempotent functions.

You can also entriely skip the open flag since it always comes together with the name, so if there is no name it means no flyout is open:
function openFlyout(name) {
  setFlyout(name);
}

function closeFlyout() {
  setFlyout(null);
}

return (
  <FlyoutContext.Provider value={{flyout, openFlyout, closeFlyout}}>
    {children}
  </FlyoutContext.Provider>
);


The fact is that if I split the toggle function, the button still has the openFlyout attribute. And when I want to close the Flyout it still acts twice and re-opens.

Oh wait, so this is something like the buttons on the top bar of StackOverflow to the right of the avatar, which open inbox and recent achievements? Clicking the button opens the box, clicking the button again closes the box, but also clicking anywhere else outside the box also closes the box - is this what you're going for? Just remove the handler fro mthe button when the flyout is open: onClick={!flyout && () => toggleFlyout("UserFlyout")} (wrapping this in a named function would be recommended)

Actually this is the outside click which is toggled before the button click. So, in the case of your code, it still doesn't work because it considers that the flyout is closed and re opens it. Is There a way to use a event.stopPropagation() in flyoutManager. I saw it on another question but I can't figure out how to use in my code because it simply crashes.

Try making a working demo (for example on CodeSandbox). It will be easier if I can play around with this

Mate I'm sorry I don't know CodeSandBox or any other website like this. I thought It would work but I have a problem in App.js with const { toggleFlyout } = useFlyout(); but it works on desktop.
Here is the link anyway : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/flyout-mgp9ry


Sandbox not found. It's likely that the Sandbox you're trying to access doesn't exist or you don't have the required permissions to access it.


There you go, now you should have access

OK, I've edited my answer, check is out

Wonderful ! Thank you very much for your precious help !
